# PHP in WAMP can not access mapped drive

Tags: php, wamp, mapped-drive

Relative:

[Mapped Network Drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592910/mapped-network-drives)

[Service not able to access a mapped drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763271/service-not-able-to-access-a-mapped-drive)

[PHP is_dir and mkdir not working on mapped network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872803/php-is-dir-and-mkdir-not-working-on-mapped-network-drive)

I know this is very old-school, but I just can't figure it out...

On a Windows 2003 with wamp (apache 2.2, PHP 5.3.10) run as a service. Following the above link, I've already made it run as `Administrator` instead of `SYSTEM`. But still no luck.

I made a `.bat` file to make it clear:

```
@echo off
whoami
net use
php -r "var_dump(scandir('Z:\\'));"
php -r "var_dump(scandir('\\\\192.168.211.86\\voice'));"
php -r "var_dump(scandir('//192.168.211.86/voice'));"
```

And if I run it in `cmd`, the result is:

```
serv2003\administrator
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           R:        \\192.168.211.86\voice    Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Z:        \\192.168.211.86\voice    Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "."
  [1]=>
  string(2) ".."
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Folder"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "."
  [1]=>
  string(2) ".."
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Folder"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "."
  [1]=>
  string(2) ".."
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Folder"
}
```

But if I run it in Apache:

```
<body><pre>
<?php
echo `C:\path\to\test.bat`;
?>
</pre></body>
```

it outputs:

```
serv2003\administrator
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unavailable  Z:        \\192.168.211.86\voice    Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.


Warning: scandir(Z:\): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
bool(false)

Warning: scandir(\\192.168.211.86\voice): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
bool(false)

Warning: scandir(//192.168.211.86/voice): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
bool(false)
```

Notice that yes there's a `R:` driving missing in Apache module, but since I'm accessing `Z:`, I assume that's not the problem.

I don't have access to the remote folder, and I can't copy all files to local system. All I need is the ability to read them in PHP. What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**:

Not sure if this matters, but I'm accessing this server via Remote Desktop (it's geographically far from me).

And the `\\192.168.211.86\voice` uses username/password to map.

All the above practice is run in the same login session.

Comment: Are the two commands running from the same login environment?  Windows does keep separate mappings for different users...

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Yes, I'm running them on the same login session. Plus, I've also tried UNC.

Comment: Have you tried running `net use` from PHP via Apache?

Comment: @Robbie Do you mean `net use Z: \\192.168.211.86`? I did tried this but it seems `Z:` is not created in this manner...

Comment: Well, `net use Z: \\192.168.211.86\voice`, yes. If you launched that from your script it should hold for the Apache space. Not tried it - just a suggestion.

Comment: @Robbie Just tried that again. After `net use Z: \\192.168.211.86\voice` in PHP, `net use` in PHP doesn't display the `Z:`, as if no drive was mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install Apache, PHP and MySQL  manually. Once I had really headache with WAMP when I try to run a code using Curl (in PHP CLI mode) and it took days to investigate what was the problem, since that day I never install pre-bundle packages even to any testing environment.

This link will guide you: http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_Apache,_PHP_and_MySQL_manually

Check the server firewall also.

Comment: I don't have completely full control on the server, so this is not a choice. Anyway, I've (somehow) solved this question by convincing the owner of the remote machine to install Apache.

Comment: Though not an option to me, I personally believe this can solve it, so I'll mark this as an answer and hopefully others may find this helpful. This is the first time I use WAMP and I found it kind of frustrating sometime, comparing to separately installed PHP.

Answer (score 0):

setup all the service is unneccessary . The problem is with wamp and apache that
when you use network drive , apache could not start , wamp's color generally yellow in this situtation or the apache gives an error . To be sure that open httpd.exe with cmd line.
You'll see an error "drive couldn't find , apache failed to start etc."
After all it's probably that you realise the problem is apache on wamp couldn't start as a service. This document will help you.

[Apache Network Drive Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431658/apache-network-drive-alias/15569986#15569986)